# Double integrals in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Determine the domain of
$$\!\!\!\!\!\!\!{\small
D \equiv
\left\{\left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\
{\large\mid}\
x \in \left[\,{-\,\frac{1}{\,\sqrt{\,{2}\,}\,},
\frac{1}{\,\sqrt{\,{2}\,}\,}}\,\right],\
y \in \left[\,{\left\vert\,{x}\,\right\vert,
\,\sqrt{\,{1 - x^{2}}\,}\,}\,\right]\right\}}
$$
in polar coordinates and draw it.

Also how would you integrate $$\int\int_D \frac{1}{1+x^2 + y^2}dA$$ which is i guess
$$\int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\int_{|x|}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{1}{1+x^2 + y^2}dydx$$

I guess in the integral you can use the polar coordinates
$$\int\int_D \frac{1}{1+r^2\cos^2(\phi) + r^2\sin^2(\phi)}rdrd\phi$$
$$\int\int_D \frac{r}{1+r^2}drd\phi$$
$$\int_{\frac{1}{4\pi}}^{\frac{3}{4\pi}}\int_0^1 \frac{r}{1+r^2}drd\phi=\int_{\frac{1}{4\pi}}^{\frac{3}{4\pi}}\left(\frac 12 \ln(1+1^2)-\frac 12\ln(1+0^2) \right)d\phi$$
$$\int_{\frac{1}{4\pi}}^{\frac{3}{4\pi}}\frac{\ln{2}}{2}d\phi=\left(\frac{3}{4\pi}\frac{\ln{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\ln{2}}{2} \right)=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{2}$$

Did I get it right?

Comment: First, *don't* use the *same* letter $D$ for the original domain and the transformed domain in polars. *What* domain you don't know how to determine? Start *drawing*.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: good advice to start drawing.  But what on earth do you mean about the *transformed* domain?  It is the same domain, just expressed in polars.

Comment: The *set* of pairs $(r,\phi)$ s.t. $(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)\in D$ is $\ne D$.

Comment: You can also view $x$, $y$, $r$, $\theta$ as functions defined over $D$, in which case the notation is fine.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: $D$ is the geometrical region defined by those points.  It doesn't matter how you describe them.  You are mapping those points to a rectangular region in another cartesian system.  But we do not do this when, for example, we perform polar plots.  Along these lines, the plot of $r=\sin{\phi}$ is the same as that of $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$.

Comment: $T(r,\phi)=(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$, $T^{-1}:D\longrightarrow D^*$ for some $D^*\ne D$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: you are not wrong, but neither is the OP.  It is fine to view $r=constant$ as an arc of a circle and $\theta=constant$ as a ray emanating from the origin, rather than horizontal and vertical lines respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture.  A simple plot reveals that the domain $D$ is simply the sector of the circle $r=1$ between two values of $\theta$.  A little thought provides those values of $\theta$ (i.e., what purpose does the absolute value serve?).

The integrand you show is also wrong, as $1+r^2 \ne 2$.

The answer I get is $(\pi/4) \log{2}$.

Comment: I think i'm starting to "get" it :D [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%7C%2C+sqrt%281-x%5E2%29+from+-1%2Fsqrt%282%29+to+1%2Fsqrt%282%29] is what you meant with the drawing?

Comment: so $\phi =[\pi/4, 3\pi/4]$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. =)

Comment: The area is basicly $1/4$ of a circle? could I use $\phi = [0,\pi/2]$?